# Does this function make use of haskell's lazy evaluation

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation

I wrote the following function to decide if a number is prime or not.

```
isPrime :: Int -> Bool
isPrime n = and (map (\x -> (n `mod` x > 0))[2..(intSquareRoot n)])

intSquareRoot :: Int -> Int
intSquareRoot n = intSq n
  where
    intSq x
      | x*x > n = intSq (x - 1)
      | otherwise = x
```

I just got started with using Haskell so this piece of code may be hideous to anyone who is trained in using it. However, I am curious if this piece of code makes use of Haskell's lazy evaluation. this part

```
(map (\x -> (n `mod` x > 0))[2..(intSquareRoot n)])
```

will create a list of booleans, if just one of these is False (so if a number between 2 and the sqrt of n divides n) then the whole thing is False using the 'and' function. But I think the whole list will be created first and then the 'and' function will be used. Is this true? If so, how can I make this faster by using lazy evaluation, so that the function stops and returns false once it finds the first divisor of n. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I'd use a `$` instead of parens before `map`; it's really a nice tool :)

Comment: Instead of `and` you can use [`any`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#v:any): `any (\x -> n `mod` x > 0) [2..intSquareRoot n]`. `any` is equivalent to: `any f = and . map f` .

Comment: @Bakuriu Actually `any f = or . map f`. You were thinking about `all f = and . map f` instead.

Comment: That `intSquareRoot` is going to be *incredibly* slow for any sort of large input. You might want to consider a loop based on the old divide-and-average trick, instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's look at the definitions of `map` and `and` to understand:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map f [] = []
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs

and :: [Bool] -> Bool
and [] = True
and (x:xs) = x && and xs
```

We'll also need the definition of `&&`:

```
(&&) :: Bool -> Bool -> Bool
True && x = x
_    && _ = False
```

It is important to note here that `&&` can short-circuit, meaning if you pass it `False && undefined`, you'll get `False` immediately.  The computation `True && undefined` will throw an error though, because the second argument has to be examined.

With `map`, we know it's lazy because `:` is lazy.  We can produce an `f x`, then later ask for the rest of the list as we need it.

So looking at the line

```
and (map f [2..intSquareRoot n])
    where f x = n `mod` x > 0
```

This can be broken down into (`n = 19`)

```
and (map f [2..intSquareRoot n])
and (map f [2..4])
and (map f (2:[3..4]))
and (f 2 : map f [3..4])
f 2  && and (map f [3..4])
True && and (map f [3..4])
and (map f [3..4])
and (map f (3:[4..4]))
and (f 3 : map f [4..4])
f 3  && and (map f [4..4])
True && and (map f [4..4])
and (map f [4..4])
and (map f (4:[]))
and (f 4 : map f [])
f 4  && and (map f [])
True && and (map f [])
and (map f [])
and []
True
```

Hopefully from this expansion you can see how only one element from the list is processed at a time, while the rest of the list can remain uncomputed until its needed.  All of these steps were performed simply through substitution directly from the function definitions.  As you might be able to see, if instead I passed in `n = 27`, when `f 3` is calculated it'll return `False` and cause the `False && and (map f [4..5])` to just return `False` without consuming the rest of the list.

Comment: @Slugger FYI, this is an example of _equational reasoning_, a term that Haskellers like to throw around.  It means that we should be able to replace a call to a function with its definition because they're equal, and then reason about its implications.  Here we replace the functions `map`, `and`, and `&&` with their definitions and are able to reason that this algorithm is lazy.

Answer (score 3):

Lists are lazy in Haskell , so

```
[2.. anything]
```

will construct a thunk that is unevaluated until you start looking at the elements.
As you demand each additional element, it will be evaluated.

`and` is lazy too, so as soon as you have a False result, the whole thing short circuits.

Answer (score 1):

You can test this easily as well, if you're not convinced by the theoretical arguments. Try replacing `(intSquareRoot n)` with some large number, say a million. Does the algorithm run a million times slower when testing whether 8 is prime, or does it stop right away?

If it stops right away (as is in fact the case), it must be lazy. Of course it *will* be a million times slower when you test 7, because 7 is prime so there's no short-circuiting to do.